# How to run Rails System tests in Heroku CI

Tags: heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

How do I configure Heroku CI to run System tests?

This is my app.json, where I included what I thought would be the necessary buildpacks:

```
    {
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "scripts": {
        "test-setup": "bin/rails assets:precompile",
        "test": "bin/rails test:system"
      },
      "addons":[
        "heroku-postgresql:in-dyno"
      ],
      "buildpacks": [
        { "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome" },
        { "url": "heroku/nodejs" },
        { "url": "heroku/ruby"}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But when I deploy, I get the following error:

```
-----> Running test command `bin/rails test:system`...
rails aborted!
Webdrivers::BrowserNotFound: Failed to find Chrome binary.
```

I suspect I am missing something very basic....

I running Rails 6.0.1 and Ruby 2.6.3.

Comment: Did you solve this? How did you configure your system tests, are they running with Chrome --headless?

Answer (score 3):

Did you setup your webdriver correctly to find the correct binary as mentioned [on the official UAT wiki page of heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-browser-and-user-acceptance-testing-uat#testing-with-selenium)?

1. Add [`gem 'webdrivers'`](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers) to your Gemfile.
2. Add the following code snippet to your test_helper.rb (as stated [on heroku buildback wiki](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome#selenium) and on [webdrivers wiki](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers/wiki/Heroku-buildpack-google-chrome)):

```rb
require 'webdrivers' # Make sure webdrivers are loaded.

chrome_bin = ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM'] if ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM'].present?

chrome_capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
  chromeOptions: {
    # You may want to use a different args
    args: %w[headless disable-gpu window-size=1400x1400],
    binary: chrome_bin
  }
)

Capybara.register_driver :heroku_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, desired_capabilities: chrome_capabilities)
end
```

3. Afterwards tell your system test to use your custom chrome driver by adding it to your `application_system_test_case.rb`.

```rb
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :heroku_chrome
end
```